# Python login with request but can't have the complet page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

It seems that I can't get the page complete with my script, yet I have checked the send request which is normally good. I created a test account for the occasion. here is my script:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests.Session() as c:

    url = 'https://www.siemens-syncoic.com/#/Login'
    USERNAME = "lj@yopmail.com"
    PASSWORD = "Password.01"
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, remenber='false')
    c.post(url, data=login_data)
    page = c.get('https://www.siemens-syncoic.com/#/Operating', timeout=(2, 5))
    print(page.status_code)
    print(bs(page.content, 'html.parser'))
```

I got this result:

```html
    200

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="2020-05-19T13:09:14" name="ClimatixICbuild-date-ui"/>
    <meta content="14.0.7444" name="ClimatixICversion-ui"/>
    <meta content="14.0.7444" name="ClimatixICversion-api"/>
    <meta content="14.0.7444" name="ClimatixICversion-connectivity-tls11"/>
    <meta content="14.0.7444" name="ClimatixICversion-connectivity-tls12"/>
    <meta content="14.0.7444" name="ClimatixICversion-connectivity-soc"/>
    <meta content="14.0.7444" name="ClimatixICversion-connectivity-sth"/>
    <meta content="© Siemens AG 2013 - 2020 All Rights Reserved" name="ClimatixICcopyright"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            console.time('load files')
            window.SERVER_CONFIG = {
                APP_ROOT_PATH: '/Frontend/dist/',
                APP_MODE_PROD: true,
                API_URL: 'https://backend.api.climatixic.com' + '/Public',
                DECIMAL_SEPERATOR: '.',
                GROUP_SEPERATOR: ',',
                DEFAULT_LANGUAGE: 'en-US',
                CURRENT_THEME: '',
                MVC_SCRIPTS: [
                    {
                        path: '/bundles/newui?v=3y6l1SmB3IYPNjlDiBaMauJJSTuX-EdgxxZoccswI9o1'
                    },
                    {
                        path: '/bundles/globalize?v=0JjlGHj5TrHXZT3Y5icAMYgxzrQFAnkGr-fjs-u5kPM1'
                    },
                    {
                        path: '/bundles/globalize/en?v=gpUbXiN0legtaAjCFj_qS8lAax3kDu08iVOL-80rCnc1'
                    },
                    {
                        script: 'Globalize.locale("en");'
                    },
                    {
                        path: '/bundles/dxwebappjs?v=vJE5ySakgAF8yjDHMgwCkfgsxA0qNyfpNCRn-zVc67M1'
                    },
                    {
                        path:  '/bundles/dxwebappjs/en-US?v=sTEBg3eGmyhji_Yof9X2ulVuLQEyZOh2tFYErmbVReA1'
                    },
                    {
                        script: 'DevExpress.ui.dxOverlay.baseZIndex(2100);'
                    },
                    {
                        path: '/Frontend/dist/old/old-content.adapter.js?v=14.0.7444'
                    }
                ],
                APP_URL: '',
                SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES : ['en-US','en-GB','de-DE','de-CH','fr-FR','it-IT','nl-NL','pl-PL','sv-SE','fi-FI','nb-NO','da-DK','cs-CZ','sk-SK','es-ES','pt-PT','hu-HU','ro-RO','el-GR','ru-RU','tr-TR','uk-UA','ja-JP','zh-CN','ko-KR'],
                MAP_PROVIDER: 'Google',
                MAP_PROVIDER_KEY: 'AIzaSyCA1pATiXFbmoPO2w5lfjZMn-CsSl0y4LE:90'
                    , EXT_AUTH_TYPE: 'siemensid'
                                                                                                                    , PROXY_SESSION_TIMEOUT: 540000
            };
        </script>
    <link href="/Frontend/dist/css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Frontend/dist/scripts/init.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="loader">
    <div class="spinner">
    <div class="rect1"></div>
    <div class="rect2"></div>
    <div class="rect3"></div>
    <div class="rect4"></div>
    <div class="rect5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="loader-text">Loading Application</div>
    </div>
    <cl-app></cl-app>
    <script src="/Frontend/dist/runtime-es2015.js?v=14.0.7444"></script>
    <script src="/Frontend/dist/polyfills-es2015.js?v=14.0.7444"></script>
    <script src="/Frontend/dist/main-es2015.js?v=14.0.7444"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But i should have a lot more html code...
It like it loading but therefore i put a timeout=(2,5) on my get()...

Comment: The data is certainly loaded by some JS, so it's not present in the HTML you just loaded.

Comment: like @ThierryLathuille said, requests don't generate JS. Try with [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) which uses a headless browser

Comment: Ok thanks i will try with selenium

Answer (score 0):

Your login doesn't work because, you are using wrong URL for login. Use headers while sending request. After login the data you are looking for is load through XHR request.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.siemens-syncoic.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://www.siemens-syncoic.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.siemens-syncoic.com/'
}

with requests.Session() as session:

    login_page_url = 'https://www.siemens-syncoic.com/#/Login'
    session.get(login_page_url)

    login_url = "https://www.siemens-syncoic.com/clx/authentication"
    login_data = {"password":"Password.01","rememberme":"false","username":"lj@yopmail.com"}
    response = session.post(login_url, json=login_data, headers=headers)

    print('LoginResponse:', response.status_code, response.content)

    payload = {"requireTotalCount":"false","requireGroupCount":"false","sort":"[{\"selector\":\"Tenant\",\"desc\":false},{\"selector\":\"Name\",\"desc\":false}]","filter":"[\"Tenant\",\"=\",\"Siemens+Proxy\"]"}

    page = session.post('https://www.siemens-syncoic.com/dxdata/dxsites', data=payload, timeout=(2, 5))
    print(page.status_code, response.content)
```